# Trouble changing Crystal Report Data Source in Code

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have an .net 3.5 SP1 application that has a number of embedded crystral reports (Version 10.5). The reports will work fine in my dev. environment, but when I move the code to production the users are getting a window asking for the login credentials.

Now I know the question of how to change the data source at runtime has been asked and answered many times over on SO. My question isn't how to do it, it is what am I doing wrong?

What happens is that the login window will appear with all the information but the database field is empty and edits are disabled on the field. When I step through the code with the debugger, ConnectionInfo has all the correct information including the database name.

```
//InvoiceHistory is the crystral report that is an embedded resource
InvoiceHistory billingHistoryReport = new InvoiceHistory();

ConnectionInfo info = ReportUtilities.GetConnectionInfo();
ReportUtilities.ConfigureLogonInfo(billingHistoryReport,info);

crystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = billingHistoryReport;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();


//Static Function Code

public static void ConfigureLogonInfo(ReportDocument _report, ConnectionInfo _conn)
{
    Tables ts = _report.Database.Tables;
    TableLogOnInfo li = new TableLogOnInfo();

    foreach (Table t in ts)
    {
        li = t.LogOnInfo;
        li.ConnectionInfo = _conn;
        t.ApplyLogOnInfo(li);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _report.Subreports.Count; i++)
    {
        Tables tbs = _report.Subreports[i].Database.Tables;
        TableLogOnInfo sli = new TableLogOnInfo();

        foreach (Table t in tbs)
        {
            sli = t.LogOnInfo;
            sli.ConnectionInfo = _conn;
            t.ApplyLogOnInfo(li);
        }
    }
}


public static ConnectionInfo GetConnectionInfo()
{
    ConnectionInfo conn = new ConnectionInfo();
    conn.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
    conn.UserID = GlobalSettings.Default.DatabaseUser;
    conn.ServerName = GlobalSettings.Default.ServerName;
    conn.Password = GlobalSettings.Default.DatabasePassword;
    conn.IntegratedSecurity = GlobalSettings.Default.UseIntegratedSecurity;
    conn.DatabaseName = GlobalSettings.Default.DatabaseName;

    return conn;
}
```

When I go through VS 2008 and go Crystal Reports -> Database -> Database Expert -> Properties

```
Database Type: OLE DB(ADO)
Provider : SQLNCLI10
Data Source: {My dev SQL SERVER SERVER Instance}
Initial Catalog: {My dev DB NAME}
User ID: {My dev User ID}
Integrated Security: false
```

EDIT:
    After unchecking "Verify on Every Print", the problem still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the ConnectionInfo object directly after clearing current datasource connections.  Change your ConfigureLogonInfo method to below:

```
public static void ConfigureLogonInfo(ReportDocument _report, ConnectionInfo _conn)
    {
        _report.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
        foreach(Table tbl in _report.Database.Tables)
        {
            tbl.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = _conn;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < _report.Subreports.Count; i++)
        {
            var sub = _report.Subreports[i];
            sub.DataSourceConnections.Clear();                
            foreach(Table tbl in sub.Database.Tables)
            {
                tbl.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = _conn;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Justin, this did not work. Still presents me with the Database login screen.

Comment: Justin, you were right with the DataSourceConnections.Clear(). However your code is wrong. You need to be calling ApplyLogOnInfo(ConnectionInfo) otherwise the new connection info never sticks;I also had to install sql native client on the client machine. If you know of any way I can bundle that with the program, I would love to hear it.